# Extending linear independent sets and relation to Ker(T) and Im(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

My Quesion:

Say I have the basis $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ for the $\ker(T)$ where $T:V \rightarrow V$ and $V$ is a vector space over the field $K$ with $\dim(T)=n$, If I extend it to become a basis for $V$ which would be $v_1,\ldots,v_k,v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n$, then why does $T(v_k+1),\ldots,T(n)$ span the image of $T$?

My thoughts:

I know from the rank nullity theorem that there are $n-k$ vectors forming the basis of the image, and I know separately that the kernel is a subset of the Image, but I do not see it necessary that all of the vectors that form a basis of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ have to come from the vectors we "added" to end up with a basis for $V$.

Comment: what do you mean by $\dim(T)=n$ ? do you mean $\dim(V)=n$ ?

Comment: Also do you mean that $T(v_{k+1})$, ... , $T(v_n)$ span the image of $T$ ?

Comment: Yes (so V has an n sized basis) and yes.

Comment: In general the kernel (of a linear operator) is not a subset of the image (of the same).

Answer (score 2):

The image of $T$ is
\begin{align*}
T(V)&=T(\mathrm{span}\{ v_1,\dots,v_k\} + \mathrm{span}\{v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\})\\
&= T(\mathrm{span}\{ v_1,\dots,v_k\}) + T(\mathrm{span}\{v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\})\\
&=\{0\}+\mathrm{span}\{T(v_{k+1}),\dots,T(v_n)\}\\
&=\mathrm{span}\{T(v_{k+1}),\dots,T(v_n)\}
\end{align*}

Comment: Is the reason for $T(v_{k+1})...T(v_n)$ spanning the image, is that we can ignore $v_1...v_k$ as these are just 0 vectors so do not span non-zero target vectors, then we can imply from this that the remaining vectors must generate the non-zero vectors and can equally form the 0 vectors so $T(v_{k+1}...T(v_n)$ must span all of V?

Comment: no, you can ignore $T(v_1)$, ... , $T(v_k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v=\sum a_iv_i$ where the $v_i$ belong in the basis that we've obtained, then $T(v)=\sum T(a_iv_i)$ while $T(a_iv_i)=0$ for $v_i\in ker(T)$, hence it follows directly that the image of $T$ is generated by the image of vectors not in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

For *any* linear map $f:V\to W$ (where $W$ may or may not be the same as $V$), the images of a basis of $V$ form a generating family for the image of $f$ (a subspace of$~W$), because every vector of the image can be formed as a linear combination of them. In your situation, since by choice the images of the first $k$ vectors  of your basis are zero, these zero vectors can be removed from the generating family while still leaving a generating family for the same (image) subspace. (Note the the remaining family could be empty, as happens when the image subspace has dimension$~0$ and therefore $k=n$; this does not prevent it from being a generating family.)

One does not need rank nullity to reach this conclusion. By contrast, rank-nullity is related to the fact that the remaining generating family for the image subspace is linearly independent, and therefore a basis of the image.